# Order by ascending utcstamp not working -- missing zero from behind the numbers (Pyspark)

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, sql-order-by

I need to order a pyspark sql dataframe by ascending order of day and month. However, due to the format of the UTC stamp, this is happening:

[image]

How can I add the zero behind the single numbers and solve this? I'm programming in pyspark. This is the code I used:

```
data_grouped = data.groupby('month','day').agg(mean('parameter')).orderBy(["month", "day"], ascending=[1, 1])
data_grouped.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cast the ordering columns to integer:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

data_grouped = data.groupby('month','day').agg(F.mean('parameter')) \
                   .orderBy(F.col("month").cast("int"), F.col("day").cast("int"))
```